# HTTPS for only one page

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

My client requires to use HTTPS on a single page only. On rest of site, simple HTTP. I know it's a bit weired but I have to. Via .htaccess it can be like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

How do I add a condition to skip that secure (`https://example.com/secure/`) page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^secure(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^secure(/.*?)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: So it's like if HTTPS is off and page is '/secure', redirect to https.
and if HTTPS is on and pages is not '/secure', redirect to http. Right?

Comment: Right and in 2nd rule. If https && uri is not starting with `/secure/` then force `http://`

Comment: Thanks. BTW, /secure/ is a page. So I should make ^secure[/]?$ right? Keeping / optional.

Comment: Yes sure it is safer to make trailing `/` optional to cover both cases (see edit).